# How to manage decimal values with trailing zeros and plain integer values in excel using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Facing issue to format below 2 values.

1. 25.25
2. 25

---

If I use #.## format then it works fine for both values. But if I want 25.25 to be displayed as 25.2500 then I have to use #.0000 format and with this format 25 also gets converted to 25.0000.
I want to format the cell based on type of Cell value but POI has only NumericCellValue which returns double.
How we can achieve if we want to display decimal values with trailing 0's and plain integer values.

Comment: How would you do this using Excel? Apache POI is only to generate Excel files or other Microsoft Office files. It cannot do what Microsoft Office is not able to do.

Comment: We can format the value of Cell of excel using apache POI and I am doing this by checking the NumericCellType but problem is numeric cell type can have both type of values one is pure integer and other is decimal. So here I want to apply separate formatting for Integer like ## and separate formatting for decimal values like #.0000 which I am not able to do.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution comes in my mind is using conditional formatting.

If a cell contains a number which **not** equals its integer part (means: is not an integer), then use number format `0.0000` else not. So the condition would be a formula: `=INT(A1)<>A1`.

But there is not a `ConditionalFormattingRule.createNumberFormatting` upto now. And using the binary `*.xls` file format, which is `HSSF` in `apache poi`, nobody had detected where conditional number formats are stored at all. So only a `XSSF` solution is possible.

In Office Open XML (`XSSF`) conditional numberformats are set in `dxf` element of `styles.xml` having `numFmt` element with attributes `numFmtId` and `formatCode`. The `numFmtId` can be got from `XSSFDataFormat.getFormat` with given `formatCode`. This `dxf` element then gets linked in worksheet's `cfRule`.

The folowing complete example shows this. It provides a method `void createNumberFormatting(XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule, short numFmtId, String formatCode)` to create a numberformatting in a given `XSSFConditionalFormattingRule`.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ConditionalFormattingNumbers {
    
 static void createNumberFormatting(XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule, short numFmtId, String formatCode) throws Exception {
  java.lang.reflect.Method getDxf = XSSFConditionalFormattingRule.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDxf", boolean.class);
  getDxf.setAccessible(true);
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDxf dxf = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDxf)getDxf.invoke(rule, true);
  if (dxf.getNumFmt() == null) dxf.addNewNumFmt();
  dxf.getNumFmt().setNumFmtId(numFmtId);
  dxf.getNumFmt().setFormatCode(formatCode);
 }
    

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./ConditionalFormattingNumbers.xlsx";
  
  XSSFDataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();

  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("INT(A1)<>A1");
  createNumberFormatting(rule, dataFormat.getFormat("0.0000"), "0.0000");
  
  XSSFConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new XSSFConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};

  CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A1000")};

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);
  
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(123);
  sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue(123.45);
  sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0).setCellValue(45);
  sheet.createRow(3).createCell(0).setCellValue(45.678);
  sheet.createRow(4).createCell(0).setCellValue(678);
  sheet.createRow(5).createCell(0).setCellValue(678.9);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```